# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, diffrentiable given function. Find $\int^b_af^{(3)}(x)\ f'(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, diffrentiable given function. Find $\int^b_af^{(3)}(x)\ f'(x)dx$ :

Hey everyone. I've tried integration by parts: let $u'= f^{(3)}(x)\Rightarrow u=f''(x), y=f'(x)\Rightarrow y'=f''(x)$
We get- $\int^b_af^{(3)}(x)\ f'(x)dx = $

$ f''(b)\ f'(b)-f''(a)\ f'(a)- \int^b_af''(x)\ f''(x)dx$ $\bigg  [u=f''(x)\Rightarrow u'=f^{(3)}(x) , y'=f''(x)\Rightarrow y=f'(x)\bigg ]$

$= f''(b)\ f'(b)-f''(a)\ f'(a)- f''(b)\ f'(b)+f''(a)\ f'(a)- \int^b_a f^{(3)}(x)\ f'(x)dx $

Hence, I get:
$ 2\int^b_af^{(3)}(x)\ f'(x)dx=0 $

Does that make sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly you must have made a mistake, if you input $f(x)=e^x$, then the integral is not $0$.

Comment: @5xum Thanks, I cannot tell where my mistake is though, how should this integral be solved?

Comment: Well you can plug in e^x and find out where the mistake is...

Comment: you have made a sign error in the second part.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is just differentiable then $\int_{a}^{b}f'''(x)f'(x)\,dx$ may be undefined. In any case, it can be pretty much anything: if $f(x)=x^m$ with $m\geq 3$ and $[a,b]=[0,1]$ the given integral equals $\frac{m^2(m-1)(m-2)}{2m-3}$.